# What should be done about in-answer or in-question greetings?

Tags: discussion, editing, new-users

I have seen a few questions or answers with "Hello!" or "Hi!" in them. Is it safe to ignore these or should I edit them out? And, since they are new users, is there a tactful way to respond *while* editing them out? They shouldn't feel they have done something terribly, horribly awful but I don't know how to do that without leaving a comment explaining myself every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be, but only if you have another reason to go in and edit -- salutations, greetings, and taglines (thanks!) are always candidates for removal if you have reason to edit a post.

I would not, however, edit a post with the *sole* reason of removing these things.

Related:
[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)